# ¿Cómo cambiar el color geoJSON Polygon?

Tags: json, mapbox

¿Como puedo cambiar el color del JSON?

Dejo el código JSON

```
"crs": null
}, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "CIR_SENA": 8,
        "DIS_ELEC": 26,
        "SHAPE_Area": 71037326.9664,
        "SHAPE_LENG": 49696.426792,
        "SHAPE_Le_1": 49621.402174
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
            [
                [-70.437901, -33.492155],
                [-70.437165, -33.497753],
                [-70.46584, -33.518459],
                [-70.469228, -33.526771],
                [-70.479795, -33.531656],
                [-70.487545, -33.54343],
                [-70.504082, -33.546484],
                [-70.521563, -33.542905],
                [-70.547123, -33.551956],
                [-70.557357, -33.560782],
                [-70.611144, -33.570546],
                [-70.611271, -33.570566],
                [-70.611332, -33.570152],
                [-70.61144, -33.569432],
                [-70.611806, -33.566944],
                [-70.612217, -33.564127],
                [-70.612516, -33.562184],
                [-70.612231, -33.555611],
                [-70.611025, -33.515193],
                [-70.611309, -33.512669],
                [-70.613594, -33.508427],
                [-70.613663, -33.508351],
                [-70.590003, -33.510157],
                [-70.541708, -33.512531],
                [-70.52464, -33.508289],
                [-70.516007, -33.501932],
                [-70.499206, -33.497778],
                [-70.485682, -33.501624],
                [-70.463101, -33.492386],
                [-70.450781, -33.495837],
                [-70.437901, -33.492155]
            ]
        ]
```

Comment: Explícate, ¿Cambiar color del JSON? ¿Cambiar el color del área de la zona mapeada? ¿Que color quieres cambiarle?.

Comment: JSON es un formato de intercambio de datos en texto, no tiene color. Podrías copia-pegarlo en un editor de texto y darle el formato que quieras.

Comment: a la web geojson.io puedes importar el geojson y luego modificar el color si quieres puedes obtenerr el código nuevo de geojson o bien exportar a lo que quieras